# How can I set Xcode Organizer to run with x86_64 binaries?

Tags: xcode, macos, fortran, x86-64, i386

I'm programming in fortran and I could use a nice interface to a debugger. Following the advice of [this page](http://www.macresearch.org/tutorial-introducing-xcode-30-organizer), I decided to give the Xcode organizer a try.

I can get my program to build fine but when I try to execute it, I get this error:

`The active architecture i386 is not present in the executable 'Run my program' which contains x86_64.`

When I scour google for help, I'm presented with the instructions on how to do so for a regular project. Since this is the organizer, I don't believe such instructions can apply to me.

How can I set the active architecture to be x86_64?

Alternatively, does anyone know where I can find some documentation or a tutorial to get ifort to interface with Xcode?

I am running the free Xcode 3.2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this problem this morning.

Xcode seems to be stocking a global parameter for your architecture build, but you can only change it from project preferences. Here is what I did to solve this, inspired from http://www.44342.com/mac-f735-t412-p1.htm:

1. Instead of organize, open an Xcode project or create empty one.
2. Select it and click the "info" button.
3. On the project info panel section *build* double-click the architecture line and replace by the one you want, I did `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) -> $(ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT))`
4. On the project info panel section build click the "Rebuild code sense index button" (didn't try without may be not necessary).
5. Restart Xcode and the problem was solved for me.

Edit: it works only for the folder you had opened in organiser, and you have to redo the 4. and 5. steps for each new one. Well it is a workaround.

Comment: I committed the bug to Apple by the way.